# sum values in pandas if they are in hierarchical order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary with keys=parents and values=children:

```
dictionary = {'100': '120', '200': '149', '760': '800', '800': '790', '150': '700', '59': '80'}
```

and a pandas dataframe

```
nodes   figures     numbers
100     triangle    0.8
120     triangle    0.2
200     square      0.3
149     square      0.2
59      square      0.9
760     circle      0.13
800     circle      0.13
790     circle      0.13
150     circle      0.13
```

For each items in figures, for each node, I would like to assign the sum of numbers values if any node is parent of the other, as follows

```
nodes   figures     numbers
100     triangle   1
120     triangle   0.2
200     square     0.5
149     square     0.2
59      square     0.9
760     circle     0.39
800     circle     0.26
790     circle     0.13
150     circle     0.13
```

I tried
    out = groupby(["figures"])['numbers'].sum()

but it doesn't return a right output

```
figures     numbers
triangle    1
square      1.4
circle      0.52
```

Comment: How deep can the tree be?  IE, can children also be parents?

Comment: Yes @Stephen Rauch, children can also be parents.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a function that iterates over each row in your dataframe and recursively searches for child rows, adding values as it goes.

```
def get_children_values(row):
    if str(row.nodes) in dictionary: # searches for a child row
        child = df[(df.figures == row.figures) & (df.nodes.astype(str) == dictionary[str(row.nodes)])]
        if not child.empty: # if a child row is found, add its numbers value
             return row.numbers + get_children_values(child.iloc[0])
    return row.numbers  # if no child is found just return the numbers value for this row
```

Lets assign the output of this to a new column for comparison:

```
df['new_numbers'] = df.apply(get_children_values, axis = 1)

print(df)

   nodes   figures  numbers  new_numbers
0    100  triangle     0.80         1.00
1    120  triangle     0.20         0.20
2    200    square     0.30         0.50
3    149    square     0.20         0.20
4     59    square     0.90         0.90
5    760    circle     0.13         0.39
6    800    circle     0.13         0.26
7    790    circle     0.13         0.13
8    150    circle     0.13         0.13
```

This should work for a tree of any depth, however if there are cycles in your tree this will fail with a recursion depth error.